# The normalizer a maximal compact subgroup of a semi-simple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, dg.differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a semi-simple real Lie group such that $|\pi_0(G)|<\infty$ and let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$.

Q1: How does one prove that $N_G(K)=K$?

So I know a nice (and low-tech) proof of this result in the special case where $G=SL_n(\mathbf{R})$. Let
$K=SO_n(\mathbf{R})$ (a maximal compact). Then the associated symmetric space of $G$, namely,  $D=G/K$ can be thought of as the set of positive definite symmetric matrices of determinant $1$ (which is the same thing as the set of positive definite quadratic forms of determinant $1$). Now let
$Q_K(x)\in D$ be the standard quadratic form with isotropy group equal to $O_n(\mathbf{R})$ (inside the full group $GL_n(\mathbf{R})$). Then if $g\in N_G(K)$, we see directly that the isotropy group of $Q_K(g^{-1}x)$ has to contain $SO_n(\mathbf{R})$ and therefore has to be equal to $O_n(\mathbf{R})$. However, if two non degenerate quadratic forms in characteristic zero have the same isotropy group then they they differ by a non-zero scalar ([see this link for a proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87751/on-the-determination-of-a-quadratic-form-from-its-isotropy-group)). Since the determinant of $g$ is equal to $1$ then the scalar has to be $1$. Thus $Q_K(x)=Q_K(g^{-1}x)$ and therefore
$g\in K$.

Q2: Is it possible to generalize the proof above in an obvious way to an arbitrary semi-simple Lie group?

I don't quite see how to use the semi-simplicity of $G$. Note that I would prefer to avoid , if possible, the existence of the Iwasawa decomposition.

Comment: I assume $\pi_0(G)$ is finite. We want $|N_G(K^0)/K^0|<\infty$. We can assume $G=H(\mathbf{R})$ for adjoint connected semisimple $H$, so $K^0 = \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{R})$ for anisotropic connected semisimple $\mathbf{K} \subset H$. Now $N_G(K^0) = N_H(\mathbf{K})(\mathbf{R})$ and $N_H(\mathbf{K})^0$ is *reductive* (!), so $N_G(K^0)/K^0 = L(\mathbf{R})$ for a reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group $L$ and $L^0(\mathbf{R})$ has no non-trivial connected compact subgroups. Thus, $L^0$ has no relative roots ($S^1\subset{\rm{SL}}_2$),so $L^0$ is anisotropic and hence $L^0(\mathbf{R})$ is compact, so $L^0=1$. QED

Comment: I meant to say at the start of the preceding comment that I also assume $G$ has finite center (this ensures $G^0$ is finite over the identity component of the group of $\mathbf{R}$-points of the adjoint connected semisimple $\mathbf{R}$-group $H$ with the same Lie algebra as $G$, which in turn underlies the justification of passage to the case when $G = H(\mathbf{R})$).  The universal cover of ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{R})$, whose center is $\mathbf{Z}$, is a counterexample otherwise (it has trivial $K$).

Comment: At least for connected groups, this question was already discussed on MO, see e.g. 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83694/normalizers-of-maximal-compact-groups

Comment: @Alain: the virtually connected case is implied by the connected case. Indeed by Mostow, if $G$ is virtually connected and $K$ is compact maximal then $KG^0=G$ and $K\cap G^0$ is maximal in $G^0$ (and equal to $K^0$). So if $N$ is the normalizer of $K$ then $N=K(N\cap G^0)$. By the connected case, since $N\cap G^0$ is contained in the normalizer of $K\cap G^0$, we have $N\cap G^0=K\cap G^0$. So $N=K$. 